# find sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

I want to find the exact sum of this expression: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}$

I've already proved that it converges by condition. 
Also, I think that it's sort of telescoping series,
because if I open it I get: 
$\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{5}...$

But I cant think of way to calculate it.

Comment: This isn't telescoping since you will never repeat a term. This has the same terms as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ but will not converge to the same sum since the order of the terms matters (or maybe it does, but that would have to be proven somehow. A priori, these are not guaranteed to converge to the same thing).

Comment: @BrianMoehring That is not necessarily true, see the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ignore no, but understand it I didn't until now - good point

Comment: @Ninad Since Robert's answer below covers all my comments and more (including dealing with the sign error) I deleted them.

Answer (score 7):

Hint. Note that if $N$ is even then
$$\begin{align}S_N&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}=
-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots-\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N-1}\\&=
\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\dots+\frac{1}{N-1}-\frac{1}{N}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n},
\end{align}$$
and
$$S_{N+1}=S_N+\frac{(-1)^{N+1}}{N+1-(-1)^{N+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}
-\frac{1}{N+2}.$$